# Export and tranfer a Cmake project

Tags: eclipse, cmake

I export my cmake project to an Eclipse project.

The problem is if I try to import the (Eclipse) project from another machine, and try to build, it can't because the Makefiles are wrong: `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, and some targets definitions are pointing on paths from the machine where was exported.

The goal is to transfer my project to another guy so he doesn't need to know nothing about cmake. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not how CMake works. Calling CMake should be easy enough. If not, write a script for your co-worker calling CMake with the required bunch of flags.

Comment: I see. Yeah, I know it's easy, but they don't agree. Actually I will create a new Eclipse project.